# "Polynomial Counter" Turing Machine

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

I need some help with this question:

Definition: A Turing-machine that is a counter for the language $L$ is called *'polynomial counter'* if there exists a polynomial $p$ s.t. **every** word $w\in L$ appears on the machine's tape starting from the $p(|w|)$ cell at most (that is, the first letter of $w$ is at cell $p(|w|)$ or before it).

Assuming that $P\neq NP$ prove/refute the following statement:
If $L\in P$ then there exists a polynomial counter for $L$.

My intuition was to prove this due to the fact that we can arrange all words of $\Sigma^*$ in a lexical order and then in a polynomial time (since $L\in P$) check if $w \in L$. However, it is just a basic intuition.

Thank you

PS: it is worth mentioning that for a counting Turing Machine there is an output tape which is a write only tape and thus the words of L keeps accumulating on this tape one after the other.

Comment: Are two words allowed to "overlap"?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, I added a clarification posted by OP in the comments of a previous answer of mine, now deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming words cant overlap, we will prove that the statement is false. Lets try to think about $\Sigma^*$ and see what happens (since as you said, it could be used to create a polynomial counter for all other languages in $P$).

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the polynomial counter will contain the words in increasing lexicographical ordering (why? try to prove this fact!)

So, let us take a look at a word $w$ with length $k=|w|$. We know that all words $w'\preceq w$ ($w'$ is lexicographically smaller than $w$) must come *before* $w$ on the tape. How many of them are there? at least $2^{k-1}$ such words exist (since $2^{k-1}$ is the number of words with length $k-1$). Even if all of those words were by any chance one letter long (which they aren't, they are $k-1$ letters long), that will still take up an entire $2^{k-1}$ cells. Therefore, $w$ can appear *only after* at least $2^{k-1}$ cells.

Clearly, $2^{k-1}$ is **not** polynomial in $k=|w|$, and hence there doesn't exist a polynomial counter for $\Sigma^*$

Comment: This is essentially the same argument as my answer.

Comment: @Steven yea, I wrote the answer and forgot to upload it -_-

Comment: @Steven although, my answer is more intuition-like, while your answer is a bit more rigorous. Its always good to have both sides!

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that words cannot overlap on the output tape.

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, pick $\Sigma^* \in \mathsf{P}$ as your language and suppose that there is a polynomial counter $T$ for $\Sigma^*$.
Let $p(|w|) = |w|^{c_1} + c_2$ with $c_1, c_2 \ge 0$ be a polynomial for such that a word $w \in L$ starts in position at most $p(|w|)$  on the output tape of $T$.

Let $W= \langle w_1, w_2, \dots, \rangle$ be the list of the  distinct words from $L$ that are written on the tape by $T$, in order.

For every $h = 0, 1, \dots$ let $L(h) = \sum_{i=1}^{h} |w_i|$.
We must have:
$$
p(|w_h|) \ge L(h-1).
$$

Suppose that, for some indices $i <j$, we have $|w_i| > |w_j|$. Then by  swapping $w_i$ and $w_j$ in $W$ we would still obtain a list $W'$ that satisfies the above property.
Formally, let $w'_h = w_h$ if $h \not\in \{i, j\}$, $w'_i = w_j$, $w'_j = w_i$, and let $L'(h) = \sum_{i=1}^{h} |w'_i|$.
For $h < i$ we have $L'(h)=L(h)$,
for $h=i, \dots, j-1$ we have $L'(h) = L(h) - |w_i| + |w_j| < L(h)$, and for
$h \ge j$ we have  $L'(i)=L(i)$.
Therefore, for $h \not\in {i,j}$:
$$
p(|w'_h|) = p(|w_h|) \ge L(h-1) \ge L'(h-1).
$$
Moreover, since $i<j$:
$$
p(|w'_i|) = p(|w_j|) \ge L(j-1) \ge L'(j-1) \ge L'(i-1).
$$
Finally:
$$
p(|w'_j|) = p(|w_i|) \ge p(|w_j|) \ge L(j-1) \ge L'(j-1).
$$

This allows us to assume, without loss of generality, that the words in $W$ appear in non-decreasing order of their length. Since $W$ must contains all words from $\Sigma^*$, the length of $w_h$ and the length of the $h$-th word from $\Sigma^*$ (in lexicographic order) must coincide.

Let $\ell > 2$ be a sufficiently large integer and define $k = 2^\ell$.

There are $2^0 + 2^1 + \dots + 2^{\ell-1} = 2^\ell - 1 = k-1$ words of length at most $\ell-1$ in $\Sigma^*$, and their total length is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\ell-1} i \cdot 2^i =  \ell \cdot 2^\ell - 2 \cdot2^{\ell} + 2 > 2^{\ell}.
$$

The length of the $k$-th word $w'$ in $\Sigma^*$ is $\ell$. Therefore we must have also $|w_k| = \ell$ and we can write:
$$
\ell^{c_1} + c_2 = p(\ell) = p(|w_k|) \ge L(k-1) = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} |w_i| = \sum_{i=0}^{\ell-1} i 2^i > 2^\ell.
$$

By choosing a sufficiently large value of $\ell$ you get a contradiction.